# My label printer stays idle while sending data to the printer....Brother QL-710w USB connected

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, brother

My label maker won't print via USB. Downloaded drivers from brother as suggested. 
I sent test pages and the jobs are completed but it still won't print. 
Verified the settings and label dimensions on localhost as well.

Ran a 'dpkg -l  | grep Brother' to confirm driver and CUPS installations

I have 16.04 installed on an AMD64 and the driver/CUPS says i386. Could this be the issue and if so, is there a fix?

Ran 'vim DEBIAN/control' and got this, if it helps.

[vim DEBIAN/control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maubn.png)

p.s I've used the same drivers to print via wifi.

Comment: Check: 'ps -e | grep -U cups'... if there is no 'cupsd' process running, then it is idle and doesn't get awakened by your program when sending data to printer. Type: 'sudo service cups restart' and try again...

Comment: 'cupsd' is running. Still did a cups restart but nothing.... 'Idle - Sending data to printer.'

Comment: during driver installation you are asked to specify a device uri... you must choose 'no' while the printer is connected with yor computer over the usb cable... go to 'system settings >> printers >> properties (right click)' and check the device uri... click on change and choose the one with 'usb:...', or try to install the drivers again...